# Sequelize throwing: "relation "users" does not exist"

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have a User model that has a hasMany association with my Item model:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    last_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    underscored: true,
  });
  User.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    User.hasMany(models.Item, {
      onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    })
  };
  return User;
};
```

And I have an Item model that belongs to User:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Item = sequelize.define('Item', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    link: DataTypes.STRING,
    user_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    underscored: true,
  });
  Item.associate = function (models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Item.belongsTo(models.User)
  };
  return Item;
};
```

When I execute `User.findAll()`

I get the error `relation "users" does not exist`.

Here is the raw SQL that is executed:

```sql
SELECT 
  "User"."id", "User"."first_name", "User"."last_name", "User"."email", 
  "User"."created_at" AS "createdAt", "User"."updated_at" AS "updatedAt", 
  "Items"."id" AS "Items.id", "Items"."title" AS "Items.title", 
  "Items"."link" AS "Items.link", "Items"."user_id" AS "Items.user_id", 
  "Items"."created_at" AS "Items.createdAt", "Items"."updated_at" AS "Items.updatedAt", 
  "Items"."user_id" AS "Items.UserId" 
FROM "users" AS "User" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "items" AS "Items" ON "User"."id" = "Items"."user_id";
```

Items attributes are prepended by "Items" which is correct but Users is prepended by "User" which is not correct. Also not sure why it says `FROM "users" AS "User"` instead of `FROM "Users"`

In my config I used `underscored: true` and I'm using a postgres database. There is a "Users" table and an "Items" table in my postgres database.

```js
"pg": "^7.12.1",
"sequelize": "^5.18.4"
"sequelize-cli": "^5.5.1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch the config/config.js from:

```js
require('dotenv').config()

module.exports = {
  development: {
    url: process.env.DEV_DATABASE_URL,
    dialect: 'postgres'
  }
}
```

to:

```js
require('dotenv').config()

module.exports = {
  development: {
    url: process.env.DEV_DATABASE_URL,
    database: 'database_development',
    dialect: 'postgres'
  }
}
```

Sequelize requires a database key in the config!

https://github.com/sequelize/cli/blob/77a9a76420e36cfbcb82fe3c9c6a12d52c768104/src/commands/database.js#L88